# Tableau Reference Line on a Table

Tags: reference, line, tableau-api

I am trying to put a reference line on a table that shows a ranking by point.

for example, if 10 teams are ranked by points, and only the top 3 teams advance to the next round, I want to draw a red line between 3rd and 4th teams.

I researched a lot and found there is no conventional way to do this (Please let me know how if I am wrong).

My one workaround idea was to split 1st-3rd teams (1st sheet) and 4th-10th teams (2nd sheet). Then, when I put them on a dashboard, place a blank sheet (filled with red color and 1pt height) between the 1st and 2nd sheets that are placed vertically.

However, the problem with this approach is that when I split the rank, then the rank column is messed up because of the filter. So, if I want to stick with this approach, I should figure out how I can rank the entire 10 teams regardless of the filter.

```
  To summarize, I guess there are three parts to this question.

1) Is there a conventional way to put a red line on a table?
2) How can I rank teams by point regardless of the filter that was used to split the teams into two?
3) Is there any other ways to solve this?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems good to me and this is what it would look like using the traditional superstore:
[image]

Probably I'm missing youre second point related to filtering the ranking column.
In my example I'm using the table calculation "rank" in order to have a dynamic value.

Can you elaborate more on this topic?

UPDATE

For reference, this is how the first worksheet is built: using a table calculation based on sales (triangle sign) as a filter for the rank from 1 to 3.
[image]

The same has been done for the second worksheet, filtering from rank 4 on:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Before I elaborate on the second topic, can you provide me a reference or explain how to do the reference line, please? If that method does not work on my case, i will elaborate more on the second point!

Comment: hi there, I just used the method you suggested: 2 worksheets (Top 3 and Other) with a floating text object having 1px as height

Comment: ohhh - if that is the case, how did you by pass the filter when you rank them??

Comment: I've updated the answer adding 2 screenshot and related how to's

Comment: I really appreciate it! Is there an way for us to use actual value instead of rank to split them?

Comment: Can you elaborate more with an actual example? 
Additionally, if the answer provided the solution, please accept the answer in order to mark the question as solved.

Comment: okay so, I see you splitted the items by using rank of sales as a filter, but I guess in my case, I should use the actual value (sales column in your case??) to split. for example, if the sales "goal" 200,000, then red line should be placed between blineders and machines to indicate which did not met the goal ---- and doing this should not mess up the rank

Comment: exactly, just create a calculated field based on your column > reference value

Comment: let me try first and will get back!

Comment: Hey Fabio Fantoni - I bumped into one more problem. I will post a separate question about this. :) Thank you so much for your help here!